# ESP32 nvs_get_blob acting irrational after restart

Tags: c++, embedded, esp32, esp-idf

I am building a small wrapper library for the NVS and WiFi functions of my ESP32-WROOM-32E aka Dev-Kit-C V4.

Right now I am trying to do the following in this exact order:

1. try to process/print the objects data from the nvs directly after restarting
2. saving a new object with the same key/value every restart to the nvs
3. try to process/print the objects data from the nvs a second time using the exact code from 1, directly after setting the value in step 2.

Problem: The Object does not get retrieved from the NVS when the board has been reset (step 1.). But it can be fully retrieved every time directly after saving it to the NVS (step 3.).

I tried some other method that are saving blobs and i32s and those worked even after a restart. Though these examples were saving integer arrays instead of userdefined Class instances.

The Serial Terminal always gives me this exact output given the below code. As you can see there is suppose to be data since blob size is the same 52 bytes, but the same code then just prints emptry quotes.

```
Blob Size: 52
SSID: "" Password: ""
Set Blob of Key: key123
Saved Value of key123 to NVS.
Blob Size: 52
SSID: "key123" Password: "ThisIsTheNewPassword"
```

This is my current code:

```
extern "C"
{
    void app_main(void);
}

#include "wholeinclude.h"
#include "nvs_wrapper.h"
#include "WiFi_Functions.h"

// #define keythatneverexists "ineverdoexist"
#define keyname "key123"

void app_main(void)
{
    vTaskDelay(4000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);

    esp_err_t err = nvs_flash_init();
    if (err == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES || err == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND)
    {
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
        err = nvs_flash_init();
    }
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(err);



    WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials *test = WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials::getCredentialFromNVS(keyname);
    if (test)
        test->printConnectionData();
    else
        std::cout << "Key was not found directly after restart.\n";



    WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials *test2 = new WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials(keyname, "ThisIsTheNewPassword");
    WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials::setCredentialToNVS(keyname, test2);



    WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials *test3 = WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials::getCredentialFromNVS(keyname);
    if (test3)
        test3->printConnectionData();
    else
        std::cout << "Key was found directly after Setting up.\n";
}
```

This here is my get function:

```
WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials *WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials::getCredentialFromNVS(std::string wifi_ssid)
{
    WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials* received_connection = nullptr;
    void *received_void_connection = received_connection;

    if (nvs_wrapper::getValueFromKey(wifi_ssid, received_void_connection) != ESP_OK)
    {
        std::cout << "Error during first get call.\n";
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        received_connection = (WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials*)received_void_connection;
        return received_connection;
    }
}
```

Which then calls this nvs_get function:

```
esp_err_t nvs_wrapper::getValueFromKey(std::string key_name, void *&retrieved_value)
{

    esp_err_t err = nvs_open(nvs_namespace_name, NVS_READWRITE, &nvs_namespace_handle);
    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open namespace\n");
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(err);
        return err;
    }

    size_t required_size;

    err = nvs_get_blob(nvs_namespace_handle, key_name.c_str(), NULL, &required_size);
    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        printf("failed get blob size\n");

        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(err);
        nvs_close(nvs_namespace_handle);
        return err;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Blob Size: " << required_size << "\n";
    }

    retrieved_value = malloc(required_size);

    err = nvs_get_blob(nvs_namespace_handle, key_name.c_str(), retrieved_value, &required_size);

    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        printf("failed to get blob data\n");
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(err);
        free(retrieved_value);
        nvs_close(nvs_namespace_handle);
        return err;
    }
    else
    {
        nvs_close(nvs_namespace_handle);
        return err;
    }
}
```

This is my set function from step 2.:

```
esp_err_t WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials::setCredentialToNVS(std::string wifi_ssid, WiFi_Functions::AP_Credentials *cred)
{
    esp_err_t err;
    err = (nvs_wrapper::setValueToKey(wifi_ssid, cred, sizeof(*cred)));

    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        printf("Failed to save Value of %s to NVS.\n", cred->getWifi_ssid().c_str());
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(err);
        return err;
    }
    printf("Saved Value of %s to NVS.\n", cred->getWifi_ssid().c_str());
    return err;
}
```

It calls this nvs_set function:

```
esp_err_t nvs_wrapper::setValueToKey(std::string key_name, void *value, size_t blob_size)
{
    esp_err_t err = nvs_open(nvs_namespace_name, NVS_READWRITE, &nvs_namespace_handle);
    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(err);
        return err;
    }


    err = nvs_set_blob(nvs_namespace_handle, key_name.c_str(), value, blob_size);

    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(err);
        nvs_close(nvs_namespace_handle);
        return err;
    }
    else
        printf("Set Blob of Key: %s\n", key_name.c_str());

    err = nvs_commit(nvs_namespace_handle);
    if (err != ESP_OK)
    {
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK_WITHOUT_ABORT(err);
        nvs_close(nvs_namespace_handle);
        return err;
    }
    nvs_close(nvs_namespace_handle);
    return err;
}
```

Comment: The tag C was misused with the shown code that is definitely not C.

Comment: You appear to be attempting to write the bytes representing an object to NVS and then to read the raw object back. That's just not going to work; you're making assumptions about the internal representation of the object that you cannot make. Also if the object allocates an memory (for instance, for storing strings...) that memory won't be written or retrieved, just the values of pointers to it, which won't be valid when it's read back. You need to write serialize/deserialize methods for the class; store the output of the serialize method and have deserialize initialize the object from NVS.

Comment: @romkey thank you very much! I totally forgot about the dyminamic allocation of the classes membervariables.
The class looks like this when I remove all functions:
```
class AP_Credentials
    {
    private:
        std::string wifi_ssid = "";
        std::string wifi_password = "";
}
```

I will read further regarding the serialization of such a class!
Thank you on clearing up my confusion :D